# Null check inside Java 8 streams forEach

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following code:

```
for (final String productId : entry.getValue()) {
    final Product pro = catalogAwareRepository.findUniqueByCatalogAndVersion(Constants.Id, productId, catalog, version, Product.class);
    if (pro != null) {
      productDTOs.add(productConverter.itemDTOfFromItem(product));
    }
}
```

I converted it to use Java 8 streams like this:

```
entry.getValue()
    .parallelStream()
    .map(productId -> catalogAwareRepository.findUniqueByCatalogAndVersion(Constants.Id, productId, catalog, version, Product.class))
    .forEach(pro -> productDTOs.add(productConverter.itemDTOfFromItem(pro)));
```

Is this the correct translation? Also, how do you perform a `null` check inside `parallelStream` operation?

Translation after Tunaki suggestion

```
entry.getValue().parallelStream().map(productId -> catalogAwareRepository.findUniqueByCatalogAndVersion(Constants.Id, productId, catalog, version, Product.class))
              .filter(Objects::nonNull).map(pro -> productDTOs.add(productConverter.itemDTOfFromItem(pro))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Use filter function

Comment: You should also avoid `forEach`. Prefer to `collect` into a new list.

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks for your comments. How can i change my forEach to collectors ?

Comment: I suggest you to go through the Stream tutorial here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/. It'll teach you how to use a collector.

Comment: @Tunaki - thanks for pointing to the tutorial

Comment: @Tunaki : i updated the translation. Could you please check and tell me if i did it correct ?

Comment: No you shouldn't call `productDTOs.add` inside your `map` operation. `map` is supposed to transform one object into another. `productDTOs` will be the result of the collect call.